# inflater.inflate canot resolve location while creating menu

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to add data to my action bar, so I created a .xml file in the menu folder like the offical andriod page said, then I put this code in my activity:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

this is the main_activity_actions in my menu folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="Search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="Settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

my imports are

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

The error I get is "main_activity_actions cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Did you import android.R?

Comment: no i didnt import any andriod.r

Comment: Don't import android.R. If want to use default resources provided by Android then use it. Your main_activity_actions.xml should be in res/menu folder.

Comment: Don't misunderstand, I didn't want him to import it, I was checking if he accidentally imported it. Also, do a clean on your project(Project>Clean...)

Comment: try ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build.

Comment: Have you saved your changes? If you do any changes then make sure to save it in eclipse. Save your project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me a while ago. Before doing anything you can try Project>Clean to see if that fixes it, if you're lucky this'll do it. R cannot be resolved under two conditions, 1st is if you import android.R and the 2nd is if you have a mistake in your xml code which causes the R.java file to not be generated. If you didn't import android.R this is probably what happened to you. You can check if your R.java file is there by looking in the gen file. You can also have problems with your build tools but most of the time this is not the case and you just messed up somewhere in your xml but you can try reinstalling them if you want. You didn't post all of xml so I can't try to help you find the error but the best way I found to debug this was to create a new Android project and start copying your xml files into it, eventually it will break and the R.java file will stop being generated and you have found your bad xml. Not the greatest debugging solution I know but it worked the best for me.

A couple of things I found interesting when trying to fix this for myself:
When assigning IDs to things in xml the @+id should be used the first time the id is referenced even if it is in another tag and @id should be used ever time after. Also you need to make sure when you right click on your project>Build Path>Configure Build path has to be in the proper order. Src then gen then private libraries then dependencies (I don't know much about this but from what I have read it can mess stuff up).